# How to fix chrome v111.x issue with selenium webdriver?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

i didn't execute my tests for some days, today i wanted to execute them. but when i execute i have a blank white page, it doesn't go to the browser. Can anyone tell me how to fix so?

selenium returns me a white blank page without going to web site

Comment: any code to provide for us?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*"); //<-this is the fix
Configuration.browserCapabilities = chromeOptions; //(for Selenide, for example)
```

Comment: it doesn't help for me. I am using serenity cucumber and i have added that argument into chrome switches. No luck

Comment: @John please check this thread, maybe it may help you https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-core/issues/3083